# connect to redis server in nestjs

Tags: redis, nestjs, node-redis

I tried to connect to the Redis server, this server is not my local
but I have this error
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16)

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { RedisModule as RedisConfigModule } from '@svtslv/nestjs-ioredis';
import { RedisService } from './service/redis.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    RedisConfigModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        config: {
          host: configService.get('REDIS_HOST'),
          port: +configService.get('REDIS_PORT'),
          password: configService.get('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
          db: +configService.get('REDIS_DB'),
        },
        connection: 'default',
      }),
    }),
  ],
  providers: [RedisService],
  exports: [RedisService],
})
export class RedisModule {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}
}
```

and this is mine  .env file

```
REDIS_URL=rediss://default:{password}@{hsot}:{port}
REDIS_HOST={hsot}
REDIS_PORT={port}
REDIS_PASSWORD={password}
```

why try to connect 127.0.0.1:6379 not my config?

Comment: Which redis client are you using?  node-redis, ioredis, something else?  What's in your `redis.service` file?